# How to pass data to javascript in flask\jinja environment?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am using VS code in a Windows 10 environment to debug a python flask\jinja application.

Python code pass data to html page without issue and `{{ formDict }}` displays data correctly.  Debugging shows there are data passed to javascript.  However, running to this line

```
var dict = json.stringfy('{{ formDict|tojson|safe }}');
```

generates this error

> toJson is not defined

Is this VS code issue that not load jinja or some other problem? Any recommendation how to resolve it?

Python code:

```
formDict = {"firstname": "Eric", "lastname": "Smith"}
return render_template("appointment.html",formDict=formDict)


html file - appintment.html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>    
            function createPointOption () {
                var dict = json.stringfy('{{ formDict|tojson|safe }}');
                ......  
            }   
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="creatPointOption()">
        ....
        <p id="test">{{formDict}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your error is `tojson is not defined`. When I ran your code, I got `json` is not defined.

Try:
    `var dict = JSON.stringify('{{ formDict|tojson|safe }}');`

Note capatilisation of `JSON`

Comment: Tried use JSON. VS code debugger showed error: "JSON NameError: name 'JSON' is not defined". This is only problem to jinja variable passed as '{{}}' in javascript. The same jiajin variable works just fine in html page.